# Show date after split it in Crystal Reports

Tags: date, split, crystal-reports, report

How can I concatenate this a date in Crystal Reports after split it.

I have this formula:

```
global numberVar d :=toNumber(mid({BAQReportParameter.Option01},4,2)); 
global numberVar m:= toNumber(left({BAQReportParameter.Option01},2));
global numberVar y:= toNumber(right({BAQReportParameter.Option01},4));
Global stringVar datetxt;  
datetext := ToText(d) + "/" + ToText(m) +"/" + ToText(y);
```

but it has an error.

Comment: I have an error in the last line.

Answer (score 1):

```
global stringvar d :=(mid({BAQReportParameter.Option01},4,2)); 
global stringvar m:= (left({BAQReportParameter.Option01},2));
global stringvar y:= (right({BAQReportParameter.Option01},4));
Global stringVar datetxt:= ToText(d + "/" + m +"/" + y);
```

Do this simple changes it will work!!